# Opening cocoapods in Swift project errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

Alright, so, unfortunately I am not able to show you why I am opening what I am but anyways:

I tried opening a pod file on Xcode and got this error:

> FSPathMakeRef(/Applications/Xcode.app) failed with error -36.

I've tried using `open -a Xcode Podfile` and just incase `open -a Xcode-beta Podfile` on **terminal**.

I do not know the source of my errors or how this even happened, and I really want to continue learning but I can't without this. Please help. This is using **TERMINAL**

Please help,
Thank you.

Comment: You can just open the pod file outside of Xcode if it is giving you problems, by just locating it in finder and then opening it. Then you can edit, then `pod install`.

Comment: @George_E_2 , I'm following a tutorial where I must open the Podfile within XCODE, and I tried  `pod install`  yet I get the same error. FSPathMakeRef(/Applications/Xcode.app) failed with error -36.
Any ideas? I do not even know why I got the error.

Comment: I don't think I will be able to find the answer, but you can leave a link to the tutorial as something may have changed in the tutorial that no longer works, causing you errors. I'm afraid I can't help :/

Comment: @George_E_2 Unfortunately, its a lecture that is part of a 10 dollar program. So, I can't link you it. : (